# Изменить файл в /data android

Tags: android, linux, adb

В терминале выполняю код:

```
echo "изменить содержимое файла " > /storage/sdcard0/fail
```

Все прекрасно работает 
НО как только я пытаюсь изменить файл в `/data/local/`
все безуспешно . Телефон Root + busybox   права предоставил терминалу 
Что в моих действиях неверно ? Как вы бы  действовали ?

Answer (score 1):

echo это команда для записи текста в файл или на экран. /data/local/ это папка, то есть Вы хотите записать текст в папку, а не в файл, и следовательно ошибка. И вообще, зачем Вам это нужно?